# Delete files that were created before today

Tags: command-line, files, find

I want to search files whose creation date is prior than today.
I do :

```
find $HOME -type f -name "myFile_*.sql.zip" -mtime +1
```

but it doesn't return anything, it should at least return one file.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Try this command: `find $HOME -iname '*.sql.zip' -atime +1`

Comment: IMO, your command should have worked if you had 1 file modified 1 day before. Check modified date of that again to make sure.

Comment: it doesn't work, is there a way to tell 'find'  to look for the date that is shown when doing ls -al ? (i don't know if it is the creation/modification date)

Comment: Well, any chance your file was created more than 24 hours before? According to `man find`: `-mtime -n` File’s  data was last modified n*24 hours ago.  See the comments for -atime to understand how rounding affects the interpretation of file modification times. I assume your file created at 1 am yesterday but now it's 3 am today, so the output your command would be correct. In this case, use `-mtime +2` instead.

Comment: when id do ls -al, I am getting the date for this file : 'Dec 9'. I assume that -mtime +1 means : files that have been created at least one day ago. Is that right? If so, I should see this file with the find command. But I can only see a file with the date : 'Nov 20'

Comment: interesting thing : if I do find $HOME -iname "*.sql.zip" -mtime +0 , I can see this file. But its date (when doing a ls -al) is Dec 9.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`find` with `-mtime +1` returns files that were modified two or more days ago.

It is a documented behavior i.e. `-mtime` ignores any fractional portion. From `man find` (Time calculation is identical in `-atime`, `-mtime` and `-ctime`):

> -atime n
>
> File  was  last  accessed  n*24 hours ago.  When find figures out how many 24-hour periods ago the file was last accessed,
>   any
>                 fractional part is ignored, so to match -atime +1, a file has to have been accessed at least two days ago.

Now if you can use couple of solutions:

1. You can do:

   ```
   find . -type f -mtime +0
   ```

   This would get you the files modified one day or more ago.

   In your case:

   ```
   find $HOME -type f -name "myFile_*.sql.zip" -mtime +0
   ```
2. To get precision like this case, you should use `-mmin` option which strictly matches minutes.

   So lets say you want to get the files that were modified more that 7 hours and 10 minutes i.e. 430 minutes ago, you can do:

   ```
   find . -type f -mmin +430
   ```

   In you case, do the calculation and replace `430` with that value:

   ```
   find $HOME -type f -name "myFile_*.sql.zip" -mtime +430
   ```
3. Another option is to do it the reverse way.

   You can create a reference file e.g. `ref.txt`:

   ```
    touch -d 'today + 2 days ago' ref.txt
   ```

   Now you can find files that were modified more recently than `ref.txt`:

   ```
   find . -type f -newer ref.txt
   ```

   In your case:

   ```
   find $HOME -type f -name "myFile_*.sql.zip" -newer ref.txt
   ```

---

Once you are satisfied with the results, you can remove the file(s) e.g.:

```
find . -type f -mmin +430 -delete
```